# /lib64/libm.so.6: version / and /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version not found

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow, centos

I built Tensorflow from source on Ubuntu 16.04 in order to create the includes and libraries for the C API. Everything worked well, now I am switching to our cluster, which runs on CentOS (CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810). If I want to start my application now, I get:

```
tabulatedCombustionFoam: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.23' not found (required by /home/elias/OpenFOAM/elias-4.1/platforms/linux64GccDPInt64Opt/lib/libtensorflow.so.1)
tabulatedCombustionFoam: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /home/elias/OpenFOAM/elias-4.1/platforms/linux64GccDPInt64Opt/lib/libtensorflow.so.1)
tabulatedCombustionFoam: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /home/elias/OpenFOAM/elias-4.1/platforms/linux64GccDPInt64Opt/lib/libtensorflow.so.1)
tabulatedCombustionFoam: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found (required by /home/elias/OpenFOAM/elias-4.1/platforms/linux64GccDPInt64Opt/lib/libtensorflow.so.1)
tabulatedCombustionFoam: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /home/elias/OpenFOAM/elias-4.1/platforms/linux64GccDPInt64Opt/lib/libtensorflow.so.1)
tabulatedCombustionFoam: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.11' not found (required by /home/elias/OpenFOAM/elias-4.1/platforms/linux64GccDPInt64Opt/lib/libtensorflow.so.1)
tabulatedCombustionFoam: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /home/elias/OpenFOAM/elias-4.1/platforms/linux64GccDPInt64Opt/lib/libtensorflow.so.1)
tabulatedCombustionFoam: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /home/elias/OpenFOAM/elias-4.1/platforms/linux64GccDPInt64Opt/lib/libtensorflow_framework.so.1)
tabulatedCombustionFoam: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /home/elias/OpenFOAM/elias-4.1/platforms/linux64GccDPInt64Opt/lib/libtensorflow_framework.so.1)
tabulatedCombustionFoam: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /home/elias/OpenFOAM/elias-4.1/platforms/linux64GccDPInt64Opt/lib/libtensorflow_framework.so.1)
tabulatedCombustionFoam: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found (required by /home/elias/OpenFOAM/elias-4.1/platforms/linux64GccDPInt64Opt/lib/libtensorflow_framework.so.1)
tabulatedCombustionFoam: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.11' not found (required by /home/elias/OpenFOAM/elias-4.1/platforms/linux64GccDPInt64Opt/lib/libtensorflow_framework.so.1)
tabulatedCombustionFoam: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by /home/elias/OpenFOAM/elias-4.1/platforms/linux64GccDPInt64Opt/lib/libtensorflow_framework.so.1)
```

**My Question is:**
Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: Probably the `libc6` on your CentOS is too old. Is upgrading it an option, or running on a less rancid platform?

Comment: I cannot change anything on the platform, but upgrading might be possible. If I use "ldd --version" on the CentOS cluster I get "ldd (GNU libc) 2.17 Copyright © 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc." On the node using Ubuntu I get "ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.27-3ubuntu1) 2.27 Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc."; However would that fix the GLIBC, GLIBCXX and CXXABI errors?

Comment: At least the `GLIBC` ones, not in a place where I can check the C++ (`libstdc++`) correspondences but I'd expect them to be similarly transparent.

Comment: Notice though that upgrading a very central library like `libc6` may well be out of scope as well if you are required to stay on a particular paleolithic OS.

Comment: Hi tripleee! I want to point out that i built the included headers and linked .so libraries on an Ubuntu system, and now these crash on CentOS. Do you think the issue could be solved by doing the tensorflow-build-from-source directly on the CentOS system where I want to use the software?

Comment: Sounds like it's worth a try at least. I have no experience with building Tensorflow or idea of it's system requirements, though.